# Excel - Change width of some cells in column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet where the top 2/3 is description and the bottom 5-6 rows are amounts. I want the amount cells to be less wide than the description cells and have not been able to do.  Everything I have tried either changes the entire column or merges cells to make wider.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: If you want some cells to be "wider" you have to [merge cells](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Merge-and-unmerge-cells-5cbd15d5-9375-4540-907f-c673a93fcedf)

Answer (score 0):

As DavidPostill said, there are only two approaches to your problem in excel

1. **Merge Cells to make description wider**
   [image]
2. **Widen cells to fit the description**
   [image]

You can make formatting changes to the description box in the first approach by doing *Left align*. For the amount box Excel will *right align* that by default or else you can right align it by hand.

If you think your question has not been answered, feel free to update your question or leave comments below